# How can I mock ioctl in D?

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, d, i2c

I want to write a D class which wraps a [I2C device driver (/dev interface -> I2C device files/character device files)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface). To break dependencies on the HW during implementation I would like to mock [ioctl()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl). How can I do this most easily?

Answer (score 4):

```
writeln("hey ioctl, your mother is a hamster and your father smells of elderberries!");
```

nah I'm just kidding.

What I'd do is prolly write a fake ioctl function that looks the same and use the import and version to trick it:

```
import core.sys.posix.sys.ioctl;

version(unittest)
int ioctl(int d, int request, ...) {
        import std.stdio;
        writeln("its a fake!");
        return 0;
}

void main() {
        ioctl(0, 0);
}
```

Compiling+running that with and without unittests will yield a different result. Your local function can be called instead of the real one.